# Turning a standard deviation function to numpy form

Tags: python, function, numpy, math, numpy-ndarray

I want to get the standard deviation for every nth number defined by number. So it takes the standard deviation of every 5th number in the list. So how would i be able to turn the function `std` down at the code below to the numpy format of `np.std`.

```
import numpy as np
number = 5
list_= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])
for i in range(len(list_)-number):
     y_mean = sum(list_[i:i+number])/number     
     #Standard Dev function = square root((first list value - y_mean)+(second list value - y_mean) + (third list value - y_mean)/n-1)
     std = (sum([(k - y_mean)**2 for k in list_[i:i+number]])/(number-1))**0.5
```

Comment: The version you provided doesn't work as `y_mean` and `i` are not defined.

Comment: @Ivan I updated the details sorry about that

Comment: Are you sure this is right: are you expecting a list of std of the same size as `list_`?

Comment: @Ivan it does work in vanilla python yes. I want to get the first 5 numbers `457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014` and calculate the standard dev and then  move one number forward so it will start from the second order to the 6th and calculate the dev of the numbers `424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008` and so on until it reaches the end of the `list_`

Comment: I have updated my answer, should be the correct result now

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you are trying to measure is the rolling standard deviation with a particular window. You can use a list comprehension combined with [`np.std`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html):

```
>>> [list_[i:i+number].std() for i in range(0, len(list_)-number)]
[22.67653382706694,
 10.394077295510364,
 14.600764816599321,
 13.828019444486458,
 ...
 11.249337331453159,
 15.436611278024934,
 13.65945977634702]
```

Edit: your implementation is incorrect, the std is defined as:

```
std = (sum([(k - y_mean)**2 for k in list_[i:i+number]])/number)**0.5
```

The sum should be divided by `number`, since `[i:i+number]` translates to the interval `[i:i+number[`, so `[i,i+number-1]`, *ie.* `i+number-1-i+1 = number` elements.

Comment: I get a type error when i run that code. I have updated the settings perhaps if you could take  another look at the details I would appreciate it

Comment: @firefireeyyy your implementation is incorrect, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head I am not sure you can use the same `np.std` function to serve in this particular manner but you can at least create your own function which can serve the same effect. It can be tricky trying to make variables the same name as functions since it causes some confusion for the program. Your code would probably work if tweaked but it seems unnecessary since numpy already has a std function built into its library. However, if you want to create a custom function which finds the standard deviation for every Nth number you can use the following code:

```
import numpy as np

data_set = np.array(
    [457.334015, 424.440002, 394.795990, 408.903992, 398.821014, 402.152008, 435.790985, 423.204987, 411.574005,
     404.424988, 399.519989, 377.181000, 375.467010, 386.944000, 383.614990, 375.071991, 359.511993, 328.865997,
     320.510010, 330.079010, 336.187012, 352.940002, 365.026001, 361.562012, 362.299011, 378.549011, 390.414001,
     400.869995, 394.773010, 382.556000])


def nthStd(x, number):
    std_dev_set = []
    for i in x[::+number-1]:
        std_dev_set.append(i)
    return std_dev_set
```

You can call the function be inserting the dataset you want to use as well as the Nth number you wish to use. You can then apply the normal `np.std` to the function and return the standard deviation.

For example, calling the function would look something like this and returns the following:

```
nthStd(data_set, 5)

OUTPUT: [457.334015, 398.821014, 411.574005, 375.46701, 359.511993, 336.187012, 362.299011, 394.77301]
```

What this returns is simply a list of all the numbers in the original dataset which are spaced Nth apart. If you want to find the standard deviation of these you can use the `np.std` function like this:

```
np.std(nthStd(data_set, 5))
```

Alternatively, you can also throw the `np.std` step into the function itself to save on space. That way the function returns the standard deviation and can be called all together.

```
def nthStd(x, number):
    std_dev_set = []
    for i in x[::+number-1]:
        std_dev_set.append(i)
    return np.std(std_dev_set) 

nthStd(data_set, 5)

OUTPUT: 35.05640152471951
```

EDIT: Based on some comments it sounds like you would like this to iterate through all valid pairs of N numbers so a list of [1,2,3,4,5,6] with a n value of 2 would yield valid lists of [1,2] [2,3] [3,4] [4,5] [5,6] and then the standard deviation is calculated per list. This change can be added to the original formula by adding another for loop like so:

```
def nthStd(x, number):
    std_dev_set = []
    std_answer = []
    for k in range(0, len(x)+1-number):
        std_dev_set.clear()
        for i in x[k:number+k]:
            std_dev_set.append(i)
        std_answer.append(np.std(std_dev_set))
    return std_answer
```